# Best way to hide a button on an HTML page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

A simple page, with the button:

```
<button id="MyButton">Hello</button>
```

The problem is:

- I need the button to show if Javascript is disabled
- I need the button to be hidden if Javascript is enabled

A simple Jquery:

```
$('#MyButton').hide();
```

Isn't sufficient as the button 'flickers', it loads and then hides itself and it's very noticeable.

The one way I've found to make this work is by using JS to hide it immediately after:

```
<button id="MyButton">Hello</button>
<script>
    document.getElementById('MyButton').style.visibility = 'hidden';
</script>
```

This seems a bit ugly and breaking a couple of good standards rules, is this the only way to hide the button without a flickering effect?

Comment: `<noscript`> is the key

Comment: Can't you just add 'style="display:none;"'?

Comment: @gdoron DOH! Missing the obvious!  That's amazing thank you, please put it in an answer if you want some points!

Comment: @TomGullen, [the answer format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10416551/601179). thanks

Comment: @andreapier if JS is disabled how do you get it to then show?

Comment: Do you want to do it with javascript? I can show you a way without flickering, but why not with `<noscript>` ?

Comment: @gdoron no, your <noscript> solution is great :)

Comment: @TomGullen. Though I'm flattered with your comment, it's not like I implemented it, only gave you a reference to others good job ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<noscript>
    <button id="MyButton">Hello</button>
</noscript>
```

> The HTML NoScript Element () defines a section of html to be inserted if a script type on the page is unsupported or if scripting is currently turned off in the browser.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/noscript)

Answer (score 14):

Sounds like a job for the noscript tag!

```
<noscript>
    <button id="MyButton">Hello</button>
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `<noscript>` element which holds a `<style>` element. `<noscript>` won't be parsed by browsers with active JavaScript. So that's:

```
<style>#MyButton { display: none; }</style>
<noscript><style> button#MyButton { display: inline; }</style></noscript>
```

Or better yet:

```
<noscript><button id="MyButton">Button</button></noscript>
```

Note I'm using `button#MyButton` to have a higher specificity value so that it will override the first method.

Answer (score 2):

use a no-js class:

```
<button id="MyButton" class="no-js">Hello</button>
```

define that class to hide the element:

```
.no-js { display: none; }
```

Then, in your ready handler, remove the no-js class - it will stay there if javascript is not enabled.

Comment: Again, will cause flicker. The button won't appear and then suddenly it will.

Comment: @Truth. If the js doesn't wait for DOM ready there won't be flickering. but `<noscript>` does it all for you out of the box, so why bother?

Comment: Which is the exact reason for my downvote. Apparently, 4 other people don't think the same.

Comment: I'll have to keep my eye open looking for that, but I haven't encountered that behavior yet. If you wait for document ready, probably a little more likely, but DOM ready? Haven't seen it yet.

Comment: @kinakuta. DOM ready == document ready. Did you mean document **load**? anyway it happens and happens a lot.

Comment: I'd be curious to see one of these many examples. I can't reproduce it in any of the tests I've mocked up, and that includes with document ready.